How do I create a separate container in Data Cloud Segments?
I want to have 'And' and 'Or' containers within my ruleset. The Data Cloud article on segmentation notes:
'You can drag attributes into their own container or combine them with other attributes in the same container to create an AND or an OR relationship between the attributes.' https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.c360_a_segment_canvas_interface.htm&type=5
I can't see how to create separate containers.
